# dojo dijit extra template wire up events

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, widget

I am creating a templated widget using dojo dijit, however a separate HTML template form with data-dojo-attach-event need to be loaded in and wire-up the events because the form is designed to be used recursively multi-levelled, i.e. to be instantiated and placed in dialogs. However, the problem is how to wire-up the events, to the method of main Widget, in the extra template using the "data-dojo-attach-event" info already specified in the template without writing code explicitly to wire-up the events handlers.

Here is the simplified code:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_OnDijitClickMixin",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojo/text!./templates/SomeWidget.html",
    "dojo/text!./templates/extraTemplate.html"
], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _OnDijitClickMixin, _TemplatedMixin,
        template, extraTemplate) {

    return declare([_WidgetBase, _OnDijitClickMixin, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: template

        // what should I do here???

        postCreate: function () {
           var self = this;

           this.inherited(arguments);

           // or, what should I do here or otherwise???
        }

        clickme: function(evt) {
           // do something
        }
    });

});
```

extraTemplate.html:

```
<div>
   <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick: clickme">button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one more widget with your extraTemplate, and define some default click handler for it:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojo/text!./extraTemplate.html"
], function (
    declare,
    _WidgetBase,
    _TemplatedMixin,
    _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
    template
) {
    return declare("Extra", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: template,
        clickHandler: function () {
        }
    });
});
```

In your "main" widget create instance of it and pass click handler into constructor:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_OnDijitClickMixin",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojo/text!./templates/SomeWidget.html",
    "./ExtraForm"

], function(
  declare, 
  _WidgetBase, 
  _OnDijitClickMixin, 
  _TemplatedMixin,
  template,
  ExtraForm
) {

    return declare([_WidgetBase, _OnDijitClickMixin, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: template

        // what should I do here???

        postCreate: function () {
           var self = this;

           this.inherited(arguments);

           let form = new ExtraForm({
               clickHandler: this.clickme
           })
        }

        clickme: function(evt) {
           // do something
        }
    });

});
```